# Linking OAuthConsumer to Xcode Project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, oauth

I want to use OAuth in my iPhone app. I found the OAuthConsummer framework, but after reading the documentation I still don't understand  how to add this in Xcode (because of my poor English...).

Firstly, is OAuthConsumer the best way to use OAuth in my iPhone app? Secondly, how do I link the OAuthConsumer framework to my Xcode project?